# Context variables in routers in Meteor iron-router

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

I have a `ProjectController` in `iron-router`. I want to make sure that `project: Projects.findOne(this.params._id)` is available in all templates on routes where `ProjectController` is used.

How can I obtain this? Right now I use

```
ProjectController = ApplicationController.extend({
  layoutTemplate: "projectLayout",
  waitOn: function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe('singleProject', this.params._id);
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      project: Projects.findOne(this.params._id),
    }
  },
  action: function () {
    this.state.set('projectId', this.params._id);
    this.render();
  },
});
```

however, on new routes where I set `data`, the `data` in `ProjectController` is overriden and hence the `project` template variable is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use another custom data method for the routes using your controller. For example, with a method called `getData`, add it to your controller and call it within the `data` method:

```
ProjectController = ApplicationController.extend({
  layoutTemplate: "projectLayout",
  waitOn: function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe('singleProject', this.params._id);
  },
  getData: function () {
    return {};
  }
  data: function () {
    return _.extend({
      project: Projects.findOne(this.params._id)
    }, this.getData());
  },
  action: function () {
    this.state.set('projectId', this.params._id);
    this.render();
  },
});
```

Then just use `getData` instead of `data` in your routes! It should work like a charm: `getData` will be overriden (as well it should, since it is only a stub in the controller), and will provide the required additional data to the real `data` method, which will always include your `project` object.

Comment: Wont I override `waitOn` from the controller every time I use `waitOn` in one of my routes?

Comment: and with this structure, I have to rely on the projectId is always set with same name (`this.params._id`). Is this the way to do it in projects having a submenu being revealed only on specific pages related to a project/user/etc.?